# In Sonar, how do I tell where lines of code were added to?

Tags: sonarqube, analysis, lines-of-code

Is there a way to drill down to see which directories/files have added lines of code?

Yesterday I see that my project added ~5k LOC.  I think Sonar is confused, as we didn't add that many, we just split a couple files into a larger set of files.

I've tried adding the LOC metric hotspot to no avail (I thought this would work because the other hotspots seem to show change based on the dropdown at the top).

I've tried drilling down into the LOC parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [sonar-users] mailing list, this is currently impossible.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3580